# SELECT ROW OF PREVIOUS DAY SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

Maybe you can help on the following code please.
I have an error on the "1". I want to select all row for the previous day if I query today. The format of the date is 2018-03-16 07:22:48.377

```
SELECT object_key, audited_changes
FROM pg_audits
WHERE source_action = 'funding'
AND 'created_at' = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using.

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals, not for indentifiers

Comment: Column created_at's data type?

Comment: created_at is timestamp

Comment: I am using PgAdmin4 to query

Comment: i am using postgres

Comment: You can't compare a string `'created_at'` to a date. Also there is no `curdate()` in Postgres and the syntax for an interval is also incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all records from any point yesterday, we can use `NOW()` with an appropriate range:

```
SELECT object_key, audited_changes
FROM pg_audits
WHERE
    source_action = 'funding' AND
    created_at >= CURRENT_DATE - 1 AND
    created_at < CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY
    created_at DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

`NOW()::date` returns the current day at midnight, so the above range targets anything on or after midnight of yesterday, but strictly earlier than midnight of today.

Comment: thanks, I don't know why it displays an error in the second "created_at"

Comment: @delalma Because I left out an `AND`.

Comment: `NOW()::date - INTERVAL '1day'` can be simplified to `current_date - 1`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A kindly stallion, you surely are!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you very much for your help. Your answer is working :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen,  Done

Answer (score 0):

> Please try it:

```
SELECT object_key, audited_changes
FROM pg_audits
WHERE source_action = 'funding'
AND DATE(created_at) =DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 1000
```